# Time passed to celery beat schedule from model object

Tags: python, django, model, celery, scheduled-tasks

I wonder how can I pass the time from the model object to the celery beat schedule in settings.py?

Do I need to import the model in settings.py and iterate over all objects?

model.py

```
class Note(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='notes')
    status = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    publish_time = models.DateTimeField()
    is_publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Task in my app:

```
@task()
def task_number_one():
    // do something
    return something
```

celery part in settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'

from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'task-number-one': {
        'task': 'noteapp.tasks.task_number_one',
        'schedule': '', # crontab(minute=put here min from model, hour=put here hour from model),
    },
}
```

Comment: In your beat schedule do you need to do something to some rows from Notes table? Will the subset of rows depend on time of task execution? Remember that it is celery that will call your beat task, not you so everything must be known to that task at the time it is called. You can pass some parameters with `args=` but those will be same each time celery beat calls your task.

Comment: you probably want to create celery task in Djnago signal `post_save` and you can pass the time to celery task there. Models are loaded after settings.py in django so waht you want is not feasible at all i think.

Comment: @MazelTov and Gre0ry, I want to monitor all models, if an hour is defined in a given model, then I want to do the task. Is such monitoring possible?

Comment: If you want to, say, fetch rows from your database on regular basis (i.e. every hour/minute etc.) and then based on your logic to update those rows then sure, you can do that and celery beat seems a good choice for that. What I struggle to understand is what do you mean "how can I pass the time from the model object" - if your model object has got a column (i.e. time stamp) then everything you have to do is to fetch your data from the database (i.e. run select) and then do something with it and as a result (possibly) update your database. You have to read from database to see what changed.

Comment: @Greg0ry Thank you for your answer. What I want to do is create an object (an email to send in the future), for this I need to pass from the model the date to the beat celery. In order not to run the tasks every second, so as not to load the server.

Comment: The idea of celery beat is that you run tasks every certain amount of time (it can be every second too if you want or whatever else you want). By the sound of your explanation I am not entirely sure what is it really you want to do. When you say "pass from the model the date to the beat celery" - I'm guessing you have something like `django` or `flask` where your users can change some data and you want a task executed when that change happens? If that's what you want then I would not use celery beat for that, I would fire async task at the time of user interaction and pass required data to it.

Comment: @Greg0ry Yes, this is an application in django. The thing is that the Email object has a date in the future - when an email will be sent. The user is only supposed to create an email object with a date, for example 05/05/2018 12:00 and an email will be sent on that day. I think that you just need to use a celery beat.

Comment: Ok, so you want to collect emails that are due for sending and then fire them all at certain time of a day? In such case beat will do this for you but you will have to fetch emails from the database within the beat task (this is what you refer as `passing the model`).

Comment: Exactly, I wanted this solution. thank you very much @Greg0ry +10